# How to get special characters in SQL output

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am joining few tables and the output is messed up. Where it should show `>`, it shows `&gt;`.  If I have 2 and a sign of Degree it shows - `2&deg` in the output.  It should show the degree symbol next to 2. I have to manually fix it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you querying the data / viewing the results?  And are you certain your data isn't actually stored that way?

Comment: Show us the SQL statement

Comment: Your strings are being HTML encoded. However, you haven't give enough information to show where this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Esoteric is correct; the data is being HTML encoded at some point. Most likely before it is inserted into the database.

If it is a requirement of your system that they are stored in a HTML encoded state, then all you need to do is decode the data after it is selected from the database and before it is displayed. I'm not aware of any functions in common RDBMSs to decode HTML; you will likely need to decode it in the front-end application which displays the data.

If it is not a requirement of your system to store the data in an encoded state, then you need to locate where it is being encoded and remove this. Again, there aren't any functions in the DBMS for encoding, so the encoding is probably taking place in the front-end system which inserts/updates the data.